# Why Angularjs factory needs another factory even it's not used

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, signalr, angularjs-factory

It's just a short question about AngularJS dependency injection.
I have two factories, factoryA and factoryB, factoryB not using factoryA but factoryB not working if factoryA is not injected to it.

Both factories use signalR: $.connection.hub.start ()

Why?

The following code works:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('factoryA', [
        function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }

angular.module('app')
        .factory('factoryB', ['factoryA',
            function (factoryA) {
                //factoryA is not used in this factory.
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }
```

The following code fails:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('factoryA', [
        function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }

angular.module('app')
        .factory('factoryB', [
            function () {
                //factoryA is not used in this factory.
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }
```

The problem is the server (hub) can receive message from client, but cannot send response (to client), only if I inject factoryA to factoryB.

Comment: Without code is hard to say, but that is possibly because `factoryB` receives as parameter `factoryA` (and maybe it is not used), but if you set the `factoryB.$inject = []` code then you have to inject all argument received in the factory function (including `factoryA`, even if not used)

Comment: Is there any error on devtools console?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: And, what do you mean with `it fails`?

Comment: There no errors but the server (hub) cannot send response to client.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. I cannot say what's happening there, with this info you provided here, since this last thing you describe in your last comment does not seem to be related to a dependency injection issue.

Comment: It's what I think too. but I solved the problem with injection of factoryA. Thank you.